# Setting Unicode Caption from Resource DLL String Table

Tags: delphi, dll, unicode, localization

I'm having trouble with Unicode characters being displayed incorrectly on my UI.  I have a resource-only DLL containing a string table used for UI localization.  I create the DLL in Delphi XE3 with a DLL-only project (just has `{$R 'lang.res' 'lang.rc'}` in the DPR file, and gives me `lang.dll`).  I've verified that my lang.rc file is in UTF-8 format with Windows CRLF line breaks.  When I load the strings from the DLL, Unicode characters are jumbled on the interface.  Here are some details.

A snippet from the string table:

```
STRINGTABLE
{
59,"180˚"
60,"90˚ CW"
61,"90˚ CCW"
}
```

Here are code snippets that illustrate the problem I'm having with Unicode characters:

```
// explicitly assigning the degrees character shows 180˚ properly
ImageMenu180Action.Caption := '180˚'; 

// getting the resource from the DLL shows some weird two-character string for the degrees character
ImageMenu90CWAction.Caption := TLangHelper.LoadStr(IDS_ImageMenuRotationCW90);

// OutputDebugString shows the degrees character in the debugger output correctly
OutputDebugString(PChar('IDS_ImageMenuRotationCW90: '+TLangHelper.LoadStr(IDS_ImageMenuRotationCW90)));
```

Here is my Delphi function used for loading strings from the resource DLL:

```
class function TLangHelper.LoadStr(ResourceId: Integer):String;
var
   Buff: String;
   L: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  if LangDllHandle = 0 then begin
    LangDllHandle := LoadLibrary(LANGUAGE_DLL_LOCATION);
    if LangDllHandle = 0 then begin
      ShowMessage('Error loading language localization resources.');
    end;
  end;
  if LangDllHandle <> 0 then begin
    L := 1024;
    SetLength(Buff, L+1);
    LoadString(LangDllHandle, ResourceId, PChar(Buff), L);
    Result := String(PChar(Buff));
  end;
end;
```

Any suggestions?

**FOLLOW-UP:**

For Chinese characters, I had to add a preceding L to the string definitions in the .rc file so that the DLL compilation recognized them as Unicode.  For example (English, Chinese Traditional, Chinese Simplified, French):

```
STRINGTABLE
{
35,"Status Bar"
1035,L"狀態欄"
2035,L"状态栏"
3035,"Barre d'état"
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the strings be UTF-16 rather then UTF-8?

Comment: Where did you see that using UTF-8 in your .rc file would lead to the right encoding in the .res file? I found [a reference from 2002](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-63889.html) that says you need to use a special command-line option to brcc32 (`-c65001`) to tell it the encoding of the .rc file. I doubt the IDE uses that option by default.

Comment: @RobKennedy That worked, appreciate it much.  For lack of documentation stating otherwise (I couldn't find any), I assumed brcc32 would default to the file's textual encoding.  Bad assumption.  It seems like this stuff should be better documented.  I can't be the only guy trying to do this.  I'll accept an answer if you want to write one.

Comment: The resource compiler will convert the text to UTF-16

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [a reference from 2002](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-63889.html) indicating that you need to tell the resource compiler how the *.rc* file is encoded. For UTF-8, that's code page 65001, so you'd run this:

```
brcc32 -c65001 lang.rc
```

Then, of course, you'd remove the `'lang.rc'` part from the `$R` directive in your code because you no longer want the IDE to invoke the resource compiler itself.

If your Delphi version is recent enough, then you can keep the full `$R` directive and instead set the `-c65001` option in the [resource-compiler configuration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resource_Compiler_Options) of your project options.

It's hard to know the encoding of a file just by looking at it. There can be many valid guesses. The `-c` option is documented, but [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BRCC32.EXE,_the_Resource_Compiler) doesn't mention when you'd need to use it, or what the IDE uses when *it* runs the resource compiler. The IDE probably just uses the default, the same as brcc32.exe, which is the system's default ANSI code page.

Comment: Can't you just set Project -> Options -> Resource Compiler -> Additional options to `-c65001` (using Delphi XE3 here)?  That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I've updated the answer. The last version of Delphi I used didn't have that option.

Comment: Very nice answer to a very nice question!

Comment: Also, one more thing, at least with XE3.  If you remove `'lang.rc'` from the `$R` directive in the .dpr file (so only `{$R 'lang.res'}`), it still persists in the .dproj file in an `<RccCompile>` section and it will still compile the .rc each time.  You have to manually delete the `<RccCompile>..</RccCompile>` for it to actually be removed from the build.  I call that a bug.

Comment: If you remove it manually, in the editor, then it is not a bug. If the IDE doesn't remove it properly, then it is a bug. You remove a .rc file through the IDE by removing it from the Project Manager's list of source files. If you do that and it is not removed from the .dproj file, then I would call it a bug.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks, I see what you're saying.  The confusing part is that, if you manually add it in the editor in the first place, then it gets added to the dproj file even though you didn't add it through the IDE.  So, when you delete the directive in the dpr file manually, the `<RccCompile>` section still persists in the dproj file, which was confusing to me--and appeared to be a bug even if not.