# Accents in Delphi resource string

Tags: delphi, unicode-string

today I have a question about resource string.
I'm realizing an application that maybe will be internationalized, so I'm using resource string. In this strings I need to use accented chars like for sample:

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN

1, "Titolo della stringa 1#Stringa da internazionalizzare che contiene caratteri tipo: àèéìòù"
2, "Titolo della stringa 2#Anche questa stringa contiene lettere accentate come: ÈÌÓÚ"
3, "Titolo della stringa 3#Altri caratteri accentati: ñäâöç"

END
```

The **.rc** file if correctly compiled by the **brcc32** utility, but when I use the **.res** file in the Delphi application the accented char are not correctly rendered. For example the **È** char is rendered as: **Ã ̂** .
There is a way to obtain the correct accented chars?

Comment: We need to know more. What encoding does your .rc file use? Which version of Delphi? Which version of brcc32?

Comment: The file is encoded in UTF-8 and I use the 5.40 version of brcc32 (distribuited with Delphi XE7)

Comment: I expect you need to encode it as UTF-16

Comment: Although you may need to switch to the ms resource compiler `RC`

Comment: Yes David: you are right! I have coded the .rc file in UTF-16 and not it work correctly. 
Thanks for your advice!!!

Comment: Although, according to this answer, you can pass -c65001 to brcc32 and stick with UTF-8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873644/setting-unicode-caption-from-resource-dll-string-table