# Resource script with localized strings for brcc32

Tags: delphi, encoding, delphi-xe7

In a Delphi XE7 project for building an ocx I have an rc-file with Russian strings for the company name, file description etc. When I open the Properties window of the resulting ocx the Russian strings are not displayed correctly (there are strings of garbage characters due to an incorrect encoding). I have tried to convert the rc-file to Windows-1251, UTF-8 and UTF-16 encodings, then tried to specified the corresponding file encoding via the #pragma code_page directive in the rc-file, then removed #pragma and specified the encoding in the project in the section of the resource compiler. In all cases I changed the VALUE "Translation" string accordingly. Nothing of the above worked for me. What is the correct way of writing and compiling an rc-file in Delphi XE7 such that the localized strings appear correctly in the Properties window?

Note 1. I build the ocx on a build server which Delphi XE7 was simply copied to  (and BDS* environment variables set manually) rather than properly installed from a distributable.

Note 2. For information my rc-file follows (the #pragma version for Windows-1251).

```
#pragma code_page(1251)
LANGUAGE LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT

1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 2,0,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION 2,0,0,0
FILEFLAGSMASK VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
FILEOS VOS__WINDOWS32
FILETYPE VFT_APP

{
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  {
    BLOCK "041904E3"
    {
      VALUE "CompanyName", "ИмяКомпании\000"
      VALUE "FileDescription", "ИмяМодуля\000"
      VALUE "FileVersion", "2.0.0.0\000"
      VALUE "InternalName", "Tools\000"
      VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright\251 2010-2014\000"
      VALUE "LegalTrademarks", "\000"
      VALUE "OriginalFilename", "Tools.ocx\000"
      VALUE "ProductName", "ИмяПродукта\000"
      VALUE "ProductVersion", "2.0.0.0\000"
      VALUE "Comments", "No Comments\000"
    }
  }

  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  {
    VALUE "Translation", 1049, 1251
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Unicode Caption from Resource DLL String Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873644/setting-unicode-caption-from-resource-dll-string-table)

Comment: As I see it you need to encode the .rc file as UTF-8 and then pass `-c65001` to `brcc32`. Personally I'd probably use the MS resource compiler, but perhaps that's just me!

Comment: Yes, originally I did exactly this, had the file in UTF-8 and set the brcc codepage to 65001 in the project. When I look inside the resulting .res I see that the string characters are encoded as expected, for example the capital Russian O (UTF-8 representation D0 9E) is written as D0 00 9E 00 (why there are additional zero bytes I don't know and assume that this is the way strings are generally stored in res-files). So it seems to me that the .res is fine and the error occurs later when the strings are read from the resource. Are there any other language settings I should check in the project?

Comment: Should be no stray zeros. The res file should be UTF-16.

Comment: I've ended up using the option to run the Windows SDK resource compiler in the project settings and having the .rc in Windows-1251. Other combinations didn't work for me. As I now have more questions than I did when I asked the original question I'm not posting this solution as the answer.